# How should I go about making a method that will compare hands from a poker game and return the best?

Tags: java

I need to start the method with a line like this:
`public static Hand chooseBestHand(ArrayList<Hand> hands) throws handException {`

I just need some hints.
edit: The reason I have an exception is for the event that two hands are tied.

Comment: My hint is to write a `Comparator<Hand>` instead.

Comment: Don't throw an exception when two hands are tied. Make them comparable and return 0.

Comment: @cricket_007 that doesn't make a lot of sense. The method isn't a comparator. It uses a comparator to return the best hand. It might makes sense to return null or Optional.empty() if there is not best hand but it doesn't make sense to return a 0 if you are comparing a list.

Comment: @sprinter I was amending the previous comment about the Comparator in response to the last part of the question. An exception shouldn't be thrown when hands are equal. A hand is a list of Cards. Personally, throwing an exception means an error has occurred and that doesn't make sense to me because equals hands would be a split pot in poker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd approach it is to write a set of classifying methods: isStraightFlush(Hand h) returns true if the hand is a straight flush, isFourOfAKind(Hand h) returns true if the hand is four of a kind, etc. down to isPair(Hand h).

Then I'd write a set of comparison methods:  compareStraightFlushs(ArrayList hands) compares a list of hands that have already been identified as straight flushs, compareFourOfAKinds(ArrayList hands) compares a list of hands that have already been identified as four of a kind, etc. Don't forget that in your compareTwoPairs, comparePair, and compareHighCard methods, you'll have to also be looking at 1, 3 and 4 "kicker" cards respectively. (Note that you don't have to look at kickers in compareThreeOfAKind even though there are two "unused" cards in the hand.)

I'd probably also write a helper method findHighCard(Hand h, Boolean isStraight) that returns the value of the highest card in the hand, but if the isStraight argument is true and the hand contains an Ace, it has to check whether the hand also contains a King in order to determine whether the Ace is used as high or low.

There are more details to consider, of course, but once you have your classifier and comparison methods in place, it will just be a matter of calling isStraightFlush for each hand, and seeing how many hits you get. If one hand returns true, that's your winner. If two or more return true, then you'll need to call compareStraightFlushs(ArrayList hands), and the one it returns is the winner. If no hands return true for isStaightFlush, then you'll move on to calling isFourOfAKind for each hand, and you'll continue on that way, calling the classifier methods in descending order until you get at least one hit, and calling the comparison methods if you ever get more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for hints so I won't propose code.

- First of all you need to define `Suit`, `Card` and `Hand` classes.
- Then you need a class (ideally an enum) that lists all the types of poker hands with methods to identify them and to compare two hands of the same type
- You can then define a `Comparator` that compares two hands by comparing their types or, if they are the same type, calling the method for that type to compare the two hands.
- Your `chooseBestHand` becomes fairly trivial: sort using the defined comparator and then take the first one. If it returns 0 when compared to the second one then throw your exception.